# creating index into different tablespace in nhibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, indexing

I am using NHibernate with Oracle. Is it possible to create multi column index to a different tablespace from my existing table ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, implementing `IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject`. I don't know if it is possible with NHibernate